# Php MySQL: How can I make a button that sorts out files by ID or file type?

Tags: php, html, sql

I was planning to put a two or more buttons just right above the table that sorts the shown files by id or filetype in ascending or descending order but i don't know where to start. here's what it looks like (image link because i don't have enough rep):
https://ibb.co/VSWYfZm

and here's the code:
`

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once '../connection.php';
$sql="SELECT * FROM upload";
$res=mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
?>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#viewdata table{
    border:1px solid #aaa;
}
#viewdata th{background:#aaa;}
#viewdata td{background:#efefef;}
#viewdata th,td{padding:5px;text-align:left;}
</style>
<table id="viewdata">
<tr>
<th>Id</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Size</th>

<th colspan=2>Action</th>
<th>Review</th>
</tr>
<?php
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
{
echo "<tr><td>";
echo $row['id'];

echo "</td><td>";
echo $row['name'];

echo "</td><td>";
echo number_format(($row['size']/1024),2) . " Kb";

//originally Normal type
$path = ($_SESSION['type'] == 'Admin') ? "./" : "../Normal/";
echo "
<td><a href='".$path."View/delete.php?data=".$row['id']."' class='del_doc'><font color=red>delete</a></td></font>
<td><a href='".$path."View/download.php?id=".$row['id']."'><font color=green>download</a></td></font>";
//originally has a </tr> besides </td>

//  headache part
echo "</td><td>";
echo $row['comment'];
echo "<td><a href='".$path."View/edcom.php?id=".$row['id']."'><font color=#a8a432></a></td></font>";
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
</table>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.del_doc').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var loc = $(this).attr('href');
            $.ajax({
                url:loc,
                error:err=>{
                    alert("Only the Admin can do that");
                    console.log(err)
                },
                success:function(resp){
                    if(resp == 1){
                        //alert("File successfully deleted");
                        getPage('<?php echo $path ?>View/View.php')
                    }
                }
            })
        })
    })
</script>
```

`

it ain't pretty but hopefully this is enough to impress the panelists.

if you are interested here's the site: http://ofdm.infinityfreeapp.com/Login/login.php
username: hk@gmail.com password: 1 (you'll be logged in as guest, also the site may look different at other devices)

Comment: Edit:

i tried this code for the $sql part: 

$sql="SELECT * FROM `upload` ORDER BY `upload`.`type` ASC";

i mean yes it did the job but what i really want to happen is that i can switch to sort by Id or Filetype in Ascending or Descending order by the click of a button

Comment: Just pass a query string e.g. `http://www.example.com/view.php?order=ASC` 
or (`http://www.example.com/view.php?order=DESC`), then based on the $_GET["order"] you do the job you want

Comment: I was login as: banana Joseph

Answer (score 0):

In your query you need to add a `ORDER BY` clause.
In the HTML, add a radio button for sort criteria.

```
<input type="radio" name="sort" valued="1" > ID
<input type="radio" name="sort" valued="2" > File Type
```

I the action script:

```
$sort = intval($_POST['sort']);
$sorts = array('', ORDER BY `ID`,' ORDER BY `FileType`);

$sql = $sql . $sorts[$sort]";
```